# Trying returning a value from a bool ref Message function

Tags: c#, winforms

my function looks like this:

```
public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message msg)
{
    if (msg.Msg == 0x202) //WM_LBUTTONUP 
    {

        Point pos = Point.Empty;
        cursor_pos.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { pos = (this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)); }));
        int xPos = (int)pos.X;
        int yPos = (int)pos.Y;
        cursor_pos.Invoke(() => cursor_pos.Text = $"x = {xPos}, y = {yPos}");
        cursor_pos.Invoke(() => cursor_pos.Text = this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position).ToString());
          
    }
    return false;
}
```

I need to get my xPos and yPos when the function is working (when i click the Left Mouse Control), and send this information to my variable in my main function which is -

```
public void Draw()
{
    RectangleF circle = new RectangleF(xPos(from function), yPos(from function), circleWidth, circleHeight);
}
```

I know my code is in shambles but I'm really green, so sorry for such things.

Comment: Can you clarify: what is the actual question here?

Comment: Sounds like `Draw` should have parameters `int xPos, int yPos` but unclear exactly what your question is. Also why are you using `.Invoke` are you mutli-threading? And why not just catch the `MouseUp` event

Comment: What possible reason could you have to Invoke in `PrefilterMessage()`? Also, note that you're filtering messages sent to any Control on a Form. In that code, the message is delivered to the intended recipient no matter what, so it's not exactly clear what you're doing there. -- Avoid cascading sync calls in that method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you are trying to achieve but what I am assuming is that regardless of the method type (which is **bool**) you want to extract some values out of that method which are of different type (which is **int**).

In this scenario you can use [out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier) parameter to extract multiple values out of your method.

---

This [article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/out-parameter-in-c-sharp-7/) explains `out` in a beginner friendly approach.

> C# out parameter is used when a method returns multiple values. When a
> parameter passes with the Out keyword/parameter in the method, then
> that method works with the same variable value that is passed in the
> method call. If variable value changes, the method parameter value
> also changes.

---

using `out` in your method will be like:

```
public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message msg, out Point cordinate)
{
    cordinate = Point.Empty;
    if (msg.Msg == 0x202) //WM_LBUTTONUP 
    {

        Point pos = Point.Empty;
        object cursor_pos = null;
        cursor_pos.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { pos = (this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)); }));
        int xPos = (int)pos.X;
        int yPos = (int)pos.Y;
        cordinate = new Point(xPos, yPos);
        cursor_pos.Invoke(() => cursor_pos.Text = $"x = {xPos}, y = {yPos}");
        cursor_pos.Invoke(() => cursor_pos.Text = this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position).ToString());
    }
    return false;
}
```

And the usage of this method will be like:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool val = PreFilterMessage(_msg, out Point Cord);
    if (Cord!=Point.Empty)
    {
        //Do Something
    }
}
```

---

you can see that I've extracted the X and Y values as a point and after checking if it's not empty I can use it further as per required logic for the application.

Comment: [PrefilterMessage()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.imessagefilter.prefiltermessage) is part of the [IMessageFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.imessagefilter) implementation. You cannot change its signature

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks.. but the the guy mentioned "my function" so I thought he wrote it.